# how could i set a constraint in Optaplanner that prefers no-allocation rather than allocation to an incompatible line?

Tags: optaplanner

In OptaPlanner, due to the limitation of line resources, I would rather not allocate, nor allocate to an incompatible line. Is any idea of how to set such constraint ?

I am expecting if there is a suggestion on setting constraints or modeling to reach the requirement.

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [over-constrained planning](https://timefold.ai/docs/timefold-solver/latest/repeated-planning/repeated-planning.html#overconstrainedPlanning).